# How was the magic number 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 in LDAP named?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Why not just use LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN in LDAP query or some easy numbers? It is defined in a header file but not everybody uses C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An OID, object identifier is the path to an uniq objects in an international tree partly maintain by the Internet [Assign Number Authority](https://www.iana.org/) (IANA).

OIDs are commonly used by the ASN1 wich is used in SNMP,LDAP, certificates etc.

So OIDs are not magic numbers, but an important components in protocols engines.

If you don't know it have a look to [OID Repository](http://www.oid-info.com/).

Comment: According to your OID repository link they are 'standardized by ITU-T, ISO, and IEC'. No mention of IANA whatsoever. At your IANA link there is no mention of OIDs.

Comment: @EJP I wrote **partly**,  the IANA assign some privates numbers, have a look to [Private Enterprise Number (PEN) Request Template](http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page). I personaly ask to IANA the root of OIDs I use in my products [{iso(1) identified-organization(3) dod(6) internet(1) private(4) enterprise(1) 10558}](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.4.1.10558).

Comment: Alright, but this still doesn't make sense: normally you find a book by its name instead of using the ISBN number right? but this is exactly like we have to use the latter one.

Comment: @NSF, You are right but OIDs provids two important things, uniqueness and somehow a reference to the provider. For Computers OIDs are simple  and native to ASN.1. I really don't understand why somebody want to delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is all part of the dread legacy of the ISO X.500 project. Everything has an OID, and this is one of them. Bad luck.